# How to edit this php check function and add additional?

Tags: php

I've got the following check below which checks if any of `strCharID1`,`strCharID2` or `strCharID3` exist in a table: `User_RaceChangeLog` and an error message will appear.

```
$sql  = 'SELECT * FROM User_RaceChangeLog r 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT_CHAR a 
                    ON ((a.strCharID1 = r.strUserID) 
                    OR (a.strCharID2 = r.strUserID) 
                    OR (a.strCharID3 = r.strUserID)) 
         WHERE a.strAccountID = ?';

if ($db->doQuery($sql, $_SESSION['strAccountID']) > 0)
{
    $this->content = Template::Load('error', 
         array('errmsg' => Template::GetLangVar('NATION_TRANSFER_ERROR_5')));
    return false;
}
```

**What I want to do?**

I am trying to add a second check if any of `strCharID1,strCharID2,strCharID3` exist in `USERDATA` table and if `Zone` column is 253 or 254 to appear the same error message?
I tried a lot of ways to achieve this, however, I dont know how to structure my query to get `USERDATA` info based on `ACCOUNT_CHAR` table - column `strCharID1,strCharID2,strCharID3` ?

It will really appreciated if someone can help me out and just post an example of what I should do. Thanks!

Comment: Where is this `Zone` column located?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing USER_DATA has strUserId and zone is a column in USER_DATA table.

```
$sql  = 'SELECT * FROM User_RaceChangeLog r 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT_CHAR a 
                ON ((a.strCharID1 = r.strUserID) 
                OR (a.strCharID2 = r.strUserID) 
                OR (a.strCharID3 = r.strUserID)) 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN USER_DATA u 
                ON ((u.strUserID = a.strCharID1) 
                OR (u.strUserID = a.strCharID1) 
                OR (u.strUserID = a.strCharID1)) 
     WHERE a.strAccountID = ?' AND u.zone in (253,254);
```